# How to pass two or more parameters to default controller of Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to pass two parameters to the default controller of Codeigniter.

Controller = **Post**

Function = **index($parm1, $parm2)**

Using the below method by setting in routes, i am able to pass only one parameter. When i pass second parameter then it display error "No page found".

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'post/index/$1';
```

How can pass two or more than two parameters?

Comment: $route['method/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'controller/method/index/$1/$2';

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maintain your routing rules like this:-

```
$route['method/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'controller/method/$1/$2';
$route['method/(:any)'] = 'controller/method/$1';
```

Comment: @Saddam Azad please up vote my answer please for appreciation.